# Object doesn't support property or method 'ajaxSubmit'

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this issue when im trying to upload a form in ie: Object doesn't support property or method 'ajaxSubmit' Here is my code:

```
function Upload() {
    ShowWait();
    uploadCompleted = false;
    $(document.forms[0]).ajaxSubmit({ success: PostUploadProcess });
    intervalHandler = setInterval(function () {
        var responseText = $("iframe").contents().find("body").html();
        if (responseText)
            PostUploadProcess(responseText);
    }, 1000);

    return false;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: most likely the ajax submit plugin isn't included. Other possibilities are you're including jQuery twice, using `$.noConflict(true)`, or something else is overriding `$`.

Comment: Simple, you haven't defined an `ajaxSubmit` function.  This is not a function that is part of jQuery.

Comment: But this only happens in IE, in chrome or firefox it works

Comment: the problem is still originating from the same issue. Figure out exactly why the method isn't defined on $. Is the plugin failing to load in IE? If so, include how you are including the plugin in your question.

Comment: are you using the [jquery forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/malsup.com/jquery/form/)?

Comment: Thax, that was, i forget using the forms. THX

Comment: I don't understand why close this issue... I had the same issue and to fix it I had to include jqueryForm script on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
needs to be separately included. its not part of jquery core.

Comment: I don't understand why close this issue... I had the same issue and to fix it I had to include jqueryForm script on my page